# Reading and processing XML using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, readfile

Hi in an attempt to learn XML I have started a mini-project and am following this totorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppzYGd0wi_c. However, the structure of my XML is a bit different to that of this video e.g. I have ids allocated to each section. I have pasted what my XML looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF=8?>
    <peopleNetwork>
     <person id="1">
      <name>Alice</name>
      <friend>Ruby</friend>
      <image>images/ruby.jpg</image>
     </person>
     <person id="2">
      <name>Tom</name>
      <friend>Katty</friend>
      <image>images/ketty.jpg</image>
     </person>
    </peopleNetwork>
```

Since I have id and the person in the video does not in his XML, would I need to process my data differently or would following the same structure work? Can someone point me to some resource / guide me how I can read and process a XML file that has data like above using JavaScript and HTML.

I have written the following code that prompts the user to select a file:

```
    var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
    input.attr("type", "file");
    input.trigger('click');
    return false;
```

But I am guessing there is more to it, for example saving the read data and processing it somehow. Whilst I have some experience in JavaScript but I have never came across reading and processing data files - therefore I am finding a really difficult - so any guidance on this would be nice.

I understand I will need to use Ajax as the person in the video is doing - one of my question is. In my data I have id however in the video the person doesn't, so I am not sure how to go about handling this.

I am a newbie in XML, but having watched the video I am guessing its something simple but I have no clue where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Are you trying to read/parse an xml file selected by user in the browser ?

Comment: @Searching yes.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can still use `input type='file'` that allows you to select a file from the user's computer.Then we use FileReader.

html

```
<div>Xml File: <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="text/xml" ></div>
<p id="MyXMLText"></p>
```

script: I'm using jquery and javascript here. This can also be achieved with pure js. We attach `onchange` event to the `input` and then use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to open and read the xml as text.

```
    $(function () {
    $("#fileInput").on('change', function (e) {
        var file = $("#fileInput")[0].files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var fileContent = reader.result;
            //Sorry cannot give you correct answer why xml parsing fails, but this has to be done here.
            fileContent = fileContent.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF=8?>', '').replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(fileContent); //xml document is ready here
            //Get all the details for person with id = 1
            $("#MyXMLText").append($(xmlDoc).find('person[id="1"]').text() + '<br/>')
            //Get the friend's details only for person with id = 1
            $("#MyXMLText").append($(xmlDoc).find('person[id="1"]>friend').text() + '<br/>')
            //Get the name details only for person with id = 2
            $("#MyXMLText").append($(xmlDoc).find('person[id="2"]>name').text() + '<br/>')
        }
    });
});
```

[parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Let us know.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to to instead of having a input in html have a div that when clicked opens a input that is in Javascript - just wondering.

Comment: You mean open the File Selection dialog when they click on a `div` instead of declaring an input on the page ? They will still have to select a file to work with. Right ?

Comment: yes, so instead of having the code for input in html to have it in javascript

Comment: Also, console.log($(xmlDoc).find("friend").text()) doesn't display anything in the console

Comment: Just to check 1 thing - instead of having friend wouldn't it be peopleNetwork because that the section that contains reference to data I want to display on my website.

Comment: One more thing - //xml document is ready here - by this comment do you mean the XML has been loaded and parsed on the webpage and now I use the .find function to loop through my data set and display it on my page.

Comment: Can you try this https://jsfiddle.net/11hp1bnh/  and tell me if it's still not working ? It should ask you to select the sample xml provided from a file chooser and display the friend name, since that's the only thing we are displaying. --(xml document ready comment) As in we have xml document ready as an `object` which we can perform other functions on. I've only used `friend` as an example here.

Comment: Works :) how would I take into account Ids e.g.  <person id="1"> and why are these used if we can extract the data without having them.

Comment: @Adam. Great. I've update the answer on how to navigate an `xml` using attributes. There are tons of resources out there on how to use them. Structure of the `xml` depends on the objective. Here each person is identified by `id` which we can use to specifically grab a person's data instead of spitting out all of them in the document..

Comment: Great thanks - you see this code <div>Xml File: <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="text/xml" ></div> is there a way to write this in Javascript instead of html because I have a button in my webpage that when clicked opens a function and I want this code to be written in html instead of htlm

Comment: Also, instead of person[id="2"]>name' can we say id.lenght - so what I mean is instead of repeating for each id data set it would be single function/code that grabs all the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128756/discussion-between-searching-and-adam).